# 'NoneType' error while running calendar api python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm working on python script which captures all my events in google calendar. this code will show the list of all the events in a day.

Below is the code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import datetime

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

import datetime

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/calendar-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.
    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.
    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Creates a Google Calendar API service object and outputs a list of the next
    10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime')
#        print(start)
        start = start[:-9]

#        print(start)
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")

        pretty_time = start.strftime("%I:%M")
        pretty_date = start.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
                
        print(event['summary'],"at",pretty_time,"on",pretty_date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

below is the error which I'm getting. Not able to find the what is the mistake I made. please help.

below is the error which I'm getting. Not able to find the what is the mistake I made. please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mbhamidipati/python-practice/change/getevents.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mbhamidipati/python-practice/change/getevents.py", line 75, in main
    start = start[:-9]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Thanks,
Sreman

Comment: Which line are you getting this error at?

Comment: You didn't include a [mre] or your full error (including which line actually threw the error, which is critical info), so you don't have enough information for us to help you, most likely. However, on the line `event['start'].get('dateTime')`, what if `None` is returned? That would mean that `start = start[:-9]` would fail with that error. That's only a wild guess though since, again, you haven't provided nearly enough info.

Comment: If you can add sample data of how events will look like, it will be helpful for others to find the problem.

Comment: @RandomDavis I'm sorry. i've corrected the question. Your guess is perfect. i'm getting error for start = start[:-9]

Comment: Okay so given that the issue is that `start` is being set to `None`, we can assume that `event['start'].get('dateTime')` is returning `None`. So, now we need to know the contents and type of `event` and/or `event['start']` in order to help.

Comment: @RandomDavis I've updated full script. I'm trying to get all the events from my google calendar on particular day.

Comment: @Sreeman the code you updated your post with now no longer contains the erroring line. How is it related?

Comment: @RandomDavis I'm extremely sorry. i copied wrong code. Please take a look now.

Comment: @Sreeman no need to apologize, mistakes happen. Also I think at this point I'm out of my league I think, but now that all the relevant info is here I expect this to be much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main thing you need to decide is how you're going to handle when

`event['start'].get('dateTime')` returns `None`

you can add a default value to  `.get('dateTime')`

Something like this, assuming that you can get a value from another key, such as `'date'`

`start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))`